# How to correct use devicemotion on JS

Tags: javascript, devicemotion

I tried to use "devicemotion" like this:`function fun(){
 alert("Work!");
}
window.addEventListener('devicemotion', fun);`
what I do wrong?

Comment: What kind of a problem occurs?

Comment: Maybe your device or browser doesn’t support this yet. Or maybe you just didn’t move …

Comment: @misorude Or maybe the alert fires when the device is seemingly not moving. I made a quick test with two phones, the event fires all the time with no break at all, nevertheless the phones are laying on a table.

Comment: Seems partially supported: https://caniuse.com/#search=devicemotion
This example https://jsfiddle.net/growf9p6/2/ doesnt work on my device